# How do you convert natural units of world coordinate system to opengl unit?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am building a physics engine, and therefore, I am also learning opengl to be able to visualize what the physics engine is doing.  I am wondering how I convert natural units (e.g. 1 meter, 1 inch, etc.) to opengl units.

I have done some research, and it seems that the opengl unit is not really defined.  Does this mean that I could map the number 0.01f to be equivalent to 1 cm.  Therefore, if I had a circle centered at cx and cy, and I wanted it to drop by 1 cm, then I could do the following?:

```
float cx = 0.05f;
float cy = 0.05f;
cy -= .01;
```

Here is some snippets of the toy code for the graphics so far:

```
void drawCircle() {
  float r = 0.05;
  int num_segments = 1000;

  glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);

  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

  float thetaStep = 2.0f*M_PI/num_segments;
  for(float theta = 0; theta < 2.0f*M_PI; theta += thetaStep) {
    float x = r * cosf(theta);
    float y = r * sinf(theta);

    glVertex2f(x+cx, y+cy);
  }

 glEnd();
 glFlush();
}

GLvoid Timer(int value) {
  cy -= 0.01;
  if(value) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
  }

  glutTimerFunc(30, Timer, value);
}
```

The above code snippets work.  It will move the ball down at a constant rate of 0.01 opengl units.

Answer (score 2):

Since the opengl coordinate system is between the values -1 and 1,  it seems the correct way is to scale.  If I want the world to be on a scale of 300 meters, then it becomes between -300 and 300.  To convert to opengl coordinate you simply divide the natural coordinate by the scaler.  For example, if I had a circle at position <0,100m> in the world coordinate system, you would convert to opengl coordinate system by dividing each component by 300; that is assuming that the opengl coordinate system is on a scale of 300 meters.  This would result to opengl coordinate <0, .3333>.

Answer (score 2):

The units you use are entirely up to you. If you want to treat 1 unit as a meter, or an inch, or a mm, that's entirely up to you. If everything is scaled accordingly, it won't make a difference to OpenGL, so choose the unit that makes sense wrt your physics engine and use those (so that you avoid the need to constantly keep converting units).

The only consideration is really whether your units can accommodate floats, or if you need to fall back to double for position values. For example, if using floats for position, and assuming 1 GL unit = 1 meter, then you'll run out of millimetre precision at about 25km from the origin.

As for saying OpenGL has a range between -1 and 1, that's entirely incorrect. That's the range of values once they have been transformed into screen space. It doesn't make any difference whether you scale those between -FLT_MAX and +FLT_MAX, or within a range of -10 to +10. You'll have the exact same result.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I have hooked this up to my Physics Engine.  I have made the following youtube video of a 1kg ball falling 100 meters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiZODHIvJ4A.  The problem is that it seems like it's falling slow as if it's falling under water.  I have set the scale to 1 GL unit = 1 meter.  I have already checked and rechecked the math of the physics engine, and it seems to be correct.  I think the problem has to do with the scale.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I did find this (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50412/defining-an-opengl-unit), which make things a little more clear.  They said that screen coordinates are not opengl coordinates.

Comment: It turns out that that it is pretty accurate.  It's faster once I take out the print statements.